# Prove the following limit

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{z \rightarrow i} z^2+1=0$$

My attempt: Let $\epsilon>0$, and let us assume that $|z-i|<\delta$, for some $\delta$. Hence

$$|z^2 +1|=|(z-i)(z+i)|<\delta|z+i|.$$ Now, suppose that $\delta <1$, so
$$|z+i|=|z-i+2i|\leq |z-i|+|2i|<\delta+2<3.$$ Then $|z^2 +1|<3\delta.$ Finally, given $\epsilon>0$, we choose $\delta<\min(1,\epsilon /3)$ and we got $|z^2 +1|<\epsilon$.

Is this right?

Comment: Which part are you unsure about?

Comment: The proof is correct.

Comment: The proof is right!

Comment: But is |2i|≤2?how?

Comment: $$"|z+i|=|z-i+2i|\leq |z-i|+|2i|<\delta+2<3."$$ I think this line has error...how you say |2i|≤2?its obviously wrong because we are taking about complex number system

Comment: Absolute value is defined for complex $a + bi$ as $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is complicated for a simple question. The function $f:z\mapsto z^2+1$ is well-defined and continued on $\mathbb C$, especially around $i$.

So $$\lim_{z\to i} f(z)=f(i)=i^2+1=-1+1=0.$$

Comment: I think you should specify the continuity of the function which is the true argument for this easy computation.

Comment: Of course you're right, I edited